# Django sorting objects with Dropdown-List / url parameter

Tags: python, html, django, sorting

I have problems with sorting objects from database in main template which are based on url parameters.
I want to sort objects on different ways. Mainly by date, price etc.
I have my form in template, my views.py function where I'm trying to get the parameter "sort=new". If I'm using checkboxes or radio then everything works. But I need to sort objects with select and option.
My template:

```
<h2>Number of adverts: {{num}}</h2>
<form action="{% url 'adverts' %}">
    <span>Sort by:</span>
    <select name="sort">
      <option value="new">newest</option>
      <option value="old">older</option>
      <option value="price_low">price low</option>
      <option value="price_high">price high</option>
      <option value="mileage_low">mileage lowest</option>
      <option value="mileage_high">mileage higher</option>
      <input type="submit" value="Sort">
    </select>
  </form>
```

My views.py function:

```
def adverts(request):
page = 'adverts'


if request.GET.get('sort', 'new'):
    adverts = Advert.objects.all().order_by('-created')
elif request.GET.get('sort','old'):
    adverts = Advert.objects.all().order_by('created')
else:
    adverts = Advert.objects.all().order_by('-mileage')

a = 0
for num in adverts:
    a += 1

context = {'adverts': adverts, 'num': a, 'page': page}

return render(request, 'adverts/adverts.html', context)
```

As I mention above. I want to sort objects which I’m printing in my template. I want it to be a Dropdown list not a checkbox or radio. Maybe I need to create a form in forms.py file and then get access to form fields in my template? I’m confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the *value* of the `sort` parameter, so:

```
def adverts(request):
    page = 'adverts'
    adverts = Advert.objects.all()
    sort_by = request.GET.get('sort')  # 🖘 obtain the value for sort
    if sort_by == 'new':
        adverts = adverts.order_by('-created')
    elif sort_by == 'old':
        adverts = adverts.order_by('created')
    else:
        adverts = adverts.order_by('-mileage')
    
    num = len(adverts)  # 🖘 use len to count the number of items
    context = {'adverts': adverts, 'num': num, 'page': page}
    return render(request, 'adverts/adverts.html', context)
```